# How to access a angular `value` outside the module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

### config.js

```js
angular.module("steam")

.value("config", {
  baseurl: "http://dev-back1.techgrind.asia/"
});
```

I have to access the value outside the module by replacing the "http://dev .." with `config.baseurl`

### test.js

```js
var frisby = require("frisby");

frisby.create("Status test")
  .get("http://dev-back1.techgrind.asia/scripts/rest.pike?request=test")
  .expectStatus(200)
  .toss();
```

Comment: i don't really understand the question, but i think you are searching for `$scope` https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Comment: No. Look at config.js . Anywhere inside the module, I can access the value by calling `config.baseurl` . But, test.js is outside the module and I want to access `config.baseurl` here. How to?

Comment: ensure that config.js is loaded before test.js - and then there are multiple ways - you could save it directly in the browser (as a global JS variable) or you use the angular conform way and create a service / factory which returns your config data. Thats the way i would try

Comment: if you use a restful server you could let your config factory ask for the configs and then you just need to inject the "Config" object into your angular controllers - do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might reach outside the module like these. But in my opinion use .constant instead of .value for constant rest endpoints etc.

```
var config = angular.injector(["ng", "module"]).get("config");
```